# Sorting and grouping per block among multiple blocks with same name in xsl

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

XML Structure:

```
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="c">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="a">
           <Rate>1.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="b">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="c">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="e">
           <Rate>2.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="f">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
```

I need each AvailableList to be grouped by "Rate" and then sorted by the attribute "Name".

The Modified XML structure should be:

```
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="b">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="c">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="a">
           <Rate>1.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="c">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
<AvailableList>
    <TimePeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="e">
           <Rate>2.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
       <DetailPeriod Name="f">
           <Rate>0.0</Rate>
       </DetailPeriod>
    </TimePeriod>
</AvailableList>
```

I have the following xslt code:

xsl:key name="RatesKey" match="DetailPeriod" use="Rate"/

```
    <xsl:for-each select="DetailPeriod[generate-id(.) =  generate-id(key('RatesKey', Rate)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('RatesKey', Rate)">
          <xsl:variable name="varCount" select="count(key('RatesKey', Rate))"/>                      
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I am still trying to group and sort. When I print the value of $varCount for the first TimePeriod, I expect to see varCount=2 when Rate=0.0 but instead I am seeing varCount=4. It is considering all the TimePeriod blocks. How do I change the code to group and sort by per TimePeriod block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need any grouping to achieve the desired output you've given in the question, just a two-level sort first numerically by rate and then alphabetically by name

```
<xsl:for-each select="DetailPeriod">
  <xsl:sort select="Rate" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:sort select="@Name" />
```

But in general, when you want to limit Muenchian grouping to group within a particular parent element you need to include something unique to that element as part of the key value, e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="RatesKey" match="DetailPeriod"
  use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::AvailableList[1]), '|', Rate)" />

<xsl:for-each select="DetailPeriod[generate-id() = generate-id(
  key('RatesKey', concat(generate-id(current()/..), '|', Rate))[1])]">
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the Muenchian grouping. I need node-sets/groups to further process this XML and hence two-level sorting would not be sufficient.